# Laravel join and select from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have Laravel 5.2  and in my SQL database I have several tables:
**`books`** with fields `title`, `author` and `year`,
**`journals`** with fields `title`, `year` and `price`
**`newspapers`** with fields `title`, `town`, `year`

I need to get a list of all titles from all three tables, where the year is 1994. I've tried to do the following

```
$titles = DB::table('books')->where('books.year', 1994)->leftjoin('journals as journals', 'books.year', '=', 'journals.year')->leftjoin('newspapers as newspapers', 'books.year', '=', 'newspapers.year')->select('books.title', 'journals.title', 'newspapers.title')->get();
```

But with this query I get entries full of `null`s, and only newspapers are filled in. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case (if the tables are not related) you should use union, no join.

```
$books = DB::table('books')->select('title')->where('year', 1994);
$journals = DB::table('journals')->select('title')->where('year', 1994);
$titles = DB::table('newspapers')->select('title')->where('year', 1994)->union($books)->union($journals)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify year column :

```
$titles = DB::table('books')
           ->where('books.year', 1994)
           ->leftjoin('journals as journals', 'books.year', '=', 'journals.year')
           ->leftjoin('newspapers as newspapers', 'books.year', '=', 'newspapers.year')
            ->select('books.title', 'journals.title', 'newspapers.title')
            ->get();
```

Comment: oh, I have it specified, I just lost it writing a post. sorry